# On Java generic function, clarification needed

Tags: java, generics

Consider:

```
public <U> void doSomethingWith(U u) {
   ...
}
```

- Method returns void
- Method gets to know the type of U when it is passed to the method

Using Java, what is `<U>` designed to represent?

**I'd like to clarify:** 
Is it a kind of predeclaration *"That thing of type U that'll be passed to you that and you don't know about .. well, it can be anything"*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Using Java, what is `<U>` designed to represent?
>
> Is it a kind of predeclaration "*That thing of type U that'll be passed to you that and you don't know about .. well, it can be anything*"?

Yes. It is called a generic type parameter. [Read more here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)

Comment: Is the purpose to predeclare, for the benefit of a compiler?

Comment: Yes, it is mostly there so that the compiler doesn't try to look for some class actually named `U`.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, U is no more descriptive than an Object class. < U > before the method is mostly used to link the class of two or more parameters, or to bind the parameter and the result. Like:

```
public <U> U doSomething(Class<U> uClass) { }
```